# Store data not updated to List

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

A listview in Sencha Touch. I have tried almost all the solutions provided in similar questions in stackoverflow. I'm not able to do get the data in store to display for this  List.

```
var alertTypeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId : 'AlertTypeStore',
    id : 'AlertTypeStore',
    fields : [ 'Description' ],
    data : [
        {Description : 'test1'},
        {Description : 'test2'}
    ]
});
Ext.define('myapp.view.alerts.Alerts', {
    extend : 'Ext.List',
    itemTpl : '{Description}',
    store : alertTypeStore,
    requires : [ 'Ext.TitleBar' ],
    xtype : 'alerttypelist',
    id : 'alertTypeList',
    itemTpl : '<div>{Description}</div>',
    config : {
        alias : "widget.alerttypelist",
        itemId : 'alertTypeList',
        cls : 'panelBackground',
        items : [ {
            xtype : 'titlebar',
            title : 'Alert Types',
            docked : 'top',
            cls : 'headerbar',
            items : [ {
                xtype : 'button',
                text : 'Back',
                id : 'subviewBackBtn'
            }]

        } ]

    }
});
```

Why isn't the two items not getting updated in the list? Please Help. Thank you. I'm a beginner in Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put the `store` and `itemTpl` in the config, not the root object.

This will work:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.alerts.Alerts', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    config: {
        itemTpl : '<div>{Description}</div>',
        store : alertTypeStore,
    }
});
```

Comment: So, if we add data to the store like this `alertTypeStore.add({Description : 'Test Desc3'})`, it will automatically get updated in the list? or should we refresh it somehow? I couldn't find proper docs on this.